# Keep Getting the error of "TypeError: 'bultin_function_or_method' object is not subsriptable"

Tags: python

The Error only occurs when hovering the mouse over the maximize button that I have created in the program.

I'm using the pygame 2.3.0 on python 3.11.2

Error Message:

```
pygame 2.3.0 (SDL 2.24.2, Python 3.11.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Prototype\main.py", line 53, in <module>
    window.Draw()
  File "e:\Prototype\apps\window.py", line 37, in Draw
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.wsize[0], self.wsize[1])
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~^^^
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
PS E:\Prototype>
```

The code is this: listed under: the directory /apps/window.py

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self, Pos: list[int, int], WinSize: list[int, int], screen: pygame.display, WindowEvent: object):
        self.screen = screen
        self.x_button = None
        self.maximize_button = None
        self.minimize_button = None
        self.running = True
        self.WindowEvent = WindowEvent
        self.pos = Pos
        self.wsize = WinSize
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.wsize[0], self.wsize[1])
        
        # Colour Sets
        self.BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
        self.WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
        self.GRAY = (99, 102, 106)
        self.LIGHTGRAY = (217, 217, 214)
        self.RED = (255, 0, 0)
    
        self.select_x_button = self.GRAY # Due to this needing a colour its set here
    
    
    def Draw(self):
        if not self.running:
            return None
        
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.wsize[0], self.wsize[1])
        
        win_x = self.rect.x                                                                 # Gets the window POS x
        win_y = self.rect.y                                                                 # Gets the window POS y
        win_size = self.rect.size                                                           # Gets the window size for x and y

        x_button_text = "X"
        x_button_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
        x_button_colour = self.BLACK
        x_button_render = x_button_font.render(x_button_text, True, x_button_colour)

        control_bar_rect = pygame.Rect(win_x, win_y, win_size[0], 32)                       # Sets the values for the control bar
        x_button_rect = pygame.Rect(win_x + win_size[0] - 32, win_y, 32, 32)                # Sets the values for the x button
        maximize_button_rect = pygame.Rect(win_x + win_size[0] - 64, win_y, 32, 32)         # Sets the values for the maximize button
        minimize_button_rect = pygame.Rect(win_x + win_size[0] - 96, win_y, 32, 32)         # Sets the values for the minimize button
        
        self.x_button = x_button_rect                                                       # Sets the Class Variable x_button to the created rect
        self.maximize_button = maximize_button_rect                                         # Sets the Class Variable maximize_button to the created rect
        self.minimize_button = minimize_button_rect                                         # Sets the Class Variable minimize_button to the created rect
        
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.WHITE, self.rect)                                # Renders Main Window
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.LIGHTGRAY, control_bar_rect)                     # Renders the bar that contains the action buttons
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.select_x_button, x_button_rect)                             # Renders the x button
        self.screen.blit(x_button_render, (x_button_rect.x, x_button_rect.y))               # Renders the x button text "X"
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.GRAY, maximize_button_rect)                      # Renders the maximize button
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.GRAY, minimize_button_rect)                      # Renders the minimize button
        
        
        self.WindowEvent(self.screen)
        return None
    
    def Update(self, mouse_pos: [int, int], mouse_pressed: [bool, bool, bool]):
        # width/2 <= mouse[0] <= width/2+140 and height/2 <= mouse[1] <= height/2+40
        if not self.running:
            return None
        
        x         = self.rect.x
        y         = self.rect.y
        size      = self.rect.size
        
        x_        = self.x_button
        minimize_ = self.minimize_button
        maximize_ = self.maximize_button
        
        
        if x_.x <= mouse_pos[0] <= x_.x + 32 and x_.y <= mouse_pos[1] <= x_.y + 32:
            self.select_x_button = self.RED
            if mouse_pressed[0] == True:
                self.running = False
        if not x_.x <= mouse_pos[0] <= x_.x + 32 and x_.y <= mouse_pos[1] <= x_.y + 32:
            self.select_x_button = self.GRAY
        
        if maximize_.x <= mouse_pos[0] <= maximize_.x + 32 and maximize_.y <= mouse_pos[1] <= maximize_.y + 32:
            winSize = self.screen.get_rect
            self.wsize = winSize
        
        return None
```

and the main project file main.py

```
from apps.window import Window



if not __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit()


pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()


WHITE  = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK  = (  0,   0,   0)
RED    = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN  = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE   = (  0,   0, 255)
YELLOW = (  0, 255, 255)
PINK   = (255,   0, 255)

# Resolution: 1920, 1080  # Average Display Resolution
# Resolution:  720,  720  # The Default Resolution
resolution = [ 720, 720 ] # The resolution for the program

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution, pygame.RESIZABLE)


def WindowEvent(screen: pygame.display):
    text = "Hello World!"
    textFont = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
    textColour = (255, 0, 0)
    textRender = textFont.render(text, True, textColour)
    screen.blit(textRender, (200, 200))
    return None


Running = True
window = Window([50, 50], [600, 400], screen, WindowEvent)
while Running:
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Running = False
    
    window.Draw()
    window.Update(mouse_pos, mouse_pressed)
    
    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

sys.exit()
```

I've tried to check for improper indentation and i've checked the value type.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with pygame. You just pass an object somewhere instead of a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
           winSize = self.screen.get_rect
           self.wsize = winSize
```

you're reassigning `self.wsize` to be the function `self.screen.get_rect` (since you're not calling that function), and trying to index into that function later on, you get your exception.

You'd want to call that function, and since it returns a [`Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and we know you want a 2-tuple of width, height:

```
           rect = self.screen.get_rect()
           self.wsize = rect.size
```